# Newton's Third Law Slope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

[image]

I know Newton's Third Law says there is an equal and opposite reaction when you apply a force. Consider the diagram of an object on a slope above.

What is the force the object is applying on the slope? Is it **mg** or **mg cos$(\theta)$**?

Comment: What is the force "f"? Where does it come from?

Comment: @nasu IMO "f" might be friction

Comment: (a) Either show $mg \cos \theta$ and $mg \sin \theta$ on the diagram, or just show $mg$. (b) To guide you towards an answer to your question, which force on the diagram is the force that the slope exerts on the object? Now apply Newton's Third law. Find a decent statement of the law, not involving 'action' and 'reaction'.

Comment: Your question is really a bit of a red herring, it's not very relevant. Just study Newton's third and work out what it can tell you about any (if any at all) motion of the bloc.

Comment: @Eagle We need the OP's input on this. It may be friction or it may be some traction force. The answer depends on which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, is there a friction between the slope and the object?

If there is friction and the object sits still, the force will be mg (this is combined from mg cos(θ) applied via pressure and mg sin(θ) applied via friction).

If there is no friction (so the object slides down and accelerates), the force will be mg cos(θ). The mg sin(θ) part of the force will instead apply to the object and accelerate it.